# External hard disk becomes extremely slow in Windows and fails to mount on Mac after using and Ubuntu

Tags: mount, hard-drive, hardware, disk

I have a 4T Seagate external hard disk (NTFS format), I used it to work with both Mac and Windows system for around 2 years.

Recently, I mounted it on a Linux Ubuntu system to backup a bunch of system files (amount: around 100K, size: ~30GB, the total usage of the hard disk is around 2.5TB). However, after that, I found that I can not mount it to Mac again, the reason is `Volume on disk2s2 timed out waiting to mount`. Then I tried it on Windows, it becomes extramely slow when I tried to copy files. For a single large file like video, the data trasition speed is around 50MB/S, but the speed for copying folder is ~100KB or even slower. It works very well on Ubuntu though.

I tried to delete the huge amount of small Ubuntu system files on the hard disk, but the situation did not get better. I tested it on Windows using HD tune, and all parameters are normal.

I have no clue of the reasons. I wonder if anyone could give me some advice on how I can fix the problem? Thank you very much for your assistance.

Comment: Slow performance like what you are describing sounds more like hardware issues to me; ie. check the drive's health using `smartctl`, `gnome-disks`, KDE partition manager, HDSentinel or whatever tool you prefer. Especially if it's a drive with long warranty (not server/enterprise grade); they can slow down (constant re-tries) to avoid errors (and warranty claims); *ie. possibly it's not OS that is cause; but where on disk it wrote to*...

Comment: Thanks for your advice. The strange thing is it works properly on Ubuntu, the data transmission speed is normally 30-50MB/s. Sometimes can even reach 100MB/s. It only has problems on Windows and Mac...quite strange. So I suspect it should somehow related to the OS.